# Jmeter remote testing exits too early

Tags: testing, jmeter

I have 3 instances in AWS with Jmeter installed - one master and two slaves.
I want to test 1M requests against my application. I have a script, which runs 100 threads concurrently 10,000 times.

When running the test on localhost or on a single instance only it runs fine.
My issue is that when I run the test using remote servers it exits immediately on both machines.  The only logs I get from this are these:

```
Starting the test on host 10.229.48.10 @ Mon Dec 02 15:21:49 UTC 2019 (1575300109383)
Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
Finished the test on host 10.229.48.10 @ Mon Dec 02 15:22:00 UTC 2019 (1575300120030)
```

I get nothing else even with verbose logging enabled.
This is the command I use to run the test:

```
JVM_ARGS="-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m" ./bin/jmeter -n -t test.jmx -R 10.229.48.10,10.
  System load:  0.0               Processes:           122                                             │229.48.23
```

Both machines are fully open to the master instance.
Why does the script run fine on a single instance but craps out when using remote hosts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general checklist for troubleshooting JMeter master-slave configuration is:

1. Check `jmeter.log` file on the master and `jmeter-server.log` on the slaves
2. Ensure that Java version is the same on master and the slaves, if it is not the same - [get the relevant (better latest) version](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) of 64-bit JDK or Server JRE
3. Ensure that JMeter version is the same on master and the slaves, if it's not the case - [get the relevant (better latest) version](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) of JMeter
4. If your test is using any of [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) - ensure that the same set of plugins is installed on all the machines. The plugins can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/)
5. If you're using any external data files, i.e. CSV files which are consumed by the [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html) - the file(s) need to be copied over to all the slaves
6. If your test relies on some [JMeter Properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html) make sure to supply the properties via [-J or -D command-line arguments on all the machines or via -G command-line arugment on the master](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) or put them into *user.properties* file

Comment: It turned out that I didn't have csv files required on remote machines. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of JDK are you using?
Is it JDK 8 or something else?
Make sure the following things,
a. Internal Networking is enabled in all three instances.
b. JDK 8 is installed from official resources.
c. You are able to communicate with the instances individually.
d. Installed JMeter from the official resource instead of "apt install jmeter"

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion mate, I got it sorted.